# Django Rest Framework basic auth vs Apache 2.4 Basic Auth - Where is my API request being authenticated?

Tags: django, apache, authentication, django-rest-framework

I have a basic DRF API incorporated into to a basic Django application, hosted on Apache 2.4.

In the Apache configs, I give authorization/access to the application to anyone on our local server, with an additional basic authentication set-up (for testing) to allow an API call from an outside server to interact with some models.

When I make a GET request to the application itself with Basic Auth credentials, I get a 200 response with content (I am denied if I do not include credentials). But when I make a GET request to a DRF API endpoint, I get a 401 Unauthorized response. The 401 suggests that the response is not being authenticated.

My question is - why would (or how does) a DRF oriented API call go looking for authentication credentials in a different location than a call to the django app itself (if that's indeed what's going on)?

The Apache configuration looks like this:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so

WSGIDaemonProcess portal python-home=/home/bio_admin/envs/dj python-path=/var/www/portal/html/bpp
WSGIScriptAlias /portal /var/www/portal/html/bpp/bioworks/wsgi.py process-group=portal
WSGIProcessGroup portal
WSGIPassAuthorization On

Alias /static/ /var/www/portal/html/bpp/static/

<Directory /var/www/portal/html>
AuthType Basic
AuthName "portal"
AuthUserFile "/var/www/portal/html/.htpasswd"
Require user bio_admin
Require ip 74.xxx.xxx.x
</Directory>
```

The DRF part of `settings.py` file looks like this:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES' : (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    )
}
```

`urls.py` for the api endpoint as well as the endpoint that returns 200 with proper auth:

```
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns
urlpatterns = [
path('projects/', views.ProjectsListView.as_view(), name='projects'),
path('api/projects/', views.projectListAPI.as_view())
]
urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

`views.py` class for the api in question:

```
class projectDetailAPI(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Project.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProjectSerializer
```

Comment: After DRF receives the credentials in the request, `BasicAuthentication` decodes them and delegates authentication to the backends registered in `settings.py`. Are you definitely transmitting the username and password in your request to DRF, and are they [correctly encoded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication#Basic_authentication_scheme)?

Comment: I am transmitting the auth credentials in the same way for the api endpoint and the regular list view url. Using httpie: `http -a user:pass http://ip/path/to/url` . The only thing that changes between a GET request that returns 200 and a GET request that returns 401 is the url. The encoded passwords are stored in the `.htpasswd` file shown in the Apache config. It may be obvious but I am not attempting to authenticate against a user/pass in any associated database, but am using only the user:pass in the `.htpasswd` file.

Comment: When you tell DRF to use BasicAuthentication, you are telling DRF to do the authentication. Having `rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication` means that you have _Apache_ doing authentication, but then you want to authenticate a second time with Django.  You probably should have one or the other.  I'd recommend using Django instead, because then each editor of the system can have a unique user id.

Comment: I understand the benefits of having user authentication in django. However, the app doesn't have a defined set of users. Access should only be granted to requests coming from the local server IP, with the exception being a list of authenticated users when calling from outside the IP. It seems like limiting by IP would be a task that Apache is better suited for. I set the 'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES' and 'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES' to blank arrays and have gotten through with Apache auth, thank you. Removing the REST_FRAMEWORK settings entirely returned a 403.

Comment: Perfect.  Yeah, omitting `DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES` does _not_ mean you have an empty permission_classes set.  It means that the settings provided by DRF are used instead of whatever you are overriding them as.  Good luck!